# A certain kind of serial downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

I apologize in advance if this seems like whining.  I have, however, observed someone - I think - systematically downvoting each new answer I provide.  It would seem to me that this sort of downvoting avoids being reversed (as a recent spate of downvotes I received did get reversed) and is thus slightly frustrating.  That said, I am aware that a) maybe my answers simply stink and deserve the downvotes, and b) the down votes don't really matter in the big picture.  I agree, but still, I can't help but think that I am unfairly being targeted.  Is the SE system able to detect such behavior?

Comment: Someone with access to the entire database could certainly detect it, but the mods cannot.

Comment: @AlexBecker: thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, only SE employees have the ability to see who exactly is voting on your answers; the moderators are only able to see general trends regarding a user. You could contact SE directly at [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/contact); since I see at least $7$ of your recent answers that have been downvoted, this might be abusive enough for them to act.

Comment: @T.Bongers: and thank you for making me feel not all that oversensitive.  I did contact the SE team at the link you provided.

Comment: @RonGordon No problem; retaliatory and abusive downvoting is extremely frustrating.

Comment: it's worth raising not just for personal reasons but also because such downvotes abuse the system as a whole because the total votes on a question or an answer don't fairly reflect the community opinion

Comment: @RonGordon If a particular user is suspected, one can make 100% sure of this by deleting downvoted answers, observing appropriate reputation changes in a few minutes and undeleting. Even without further actions the knowledge of the origin of downvotes makes (at least me) feel a lot better.

Comment: @O.L.: How does one observe appropriate rep changes?

Comment: @RonGordon Open the page of the user X in question and record his reputation. Delete your downvoted answer. Wait a few minutes so that the system implements the reputation changes (in particular, your own reputation should decrease by appropriate amount) and then refresh the page of X. If he was at the origin of the downvote, his reputation will be *increased* by 1. Then undelete your answer, wait again and refresh the page of X. His reputation will decrease back by 1.

Comment: @O.L.: Ah, somehow I missed the part about having a suspect.  I do not have one, so I will wait for the SE folks to get back to me.

Comment: This is a first world problem if I ever saw one. Hope the perp doesn't escape swift retribution though.

Comment: The question is, will the user that has downvoted you get punished for abusing the reputation system? Like a temporal ban or something? Do we have a rule for that? I think we need one.

Comment: If it is one person, I would like the downvotes reversed, as well as every subsequent downvote reversed if necessary.  I would also like that person to receive a warning and, if the behavior continues, to have his/her account suspended.  But who knows; as I said, maybe my answers just stink.

Comment: @RonGordon It's not just you. I've had a few answers recently downvoted. And I don't think the downvotes have anything to do with the answers themselves. It might be the same person. And I think I may know who it is. But I've only upvoted his answers. So I don't know he would be taking his frustrations out on me. We can talk about it through email if you like.

Comment: @RandomVariable: feel free to email me at rlgordonma at gmail dot com

Comment: @AlexBecker The moderator user-panel has information you might find useful. Let's open a private chat session at your convenience and I can walk you through finding this information, or I can contact you at the email you display publicly in your profile.

Comment: Did this turn out to be a real thing?

Comment: @MarkHurd: yes it did, and several other active, high-rep users were targeted at the time.  I did have many downvotes reversed eventually and I consider the issue addressed, for the time being.