# Question regarding the standards of the site. Need help. Someone mass downvoting my posts.

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

(I'm trying to avoid this as hard as I could in past, but someone finally make me do it.)

(Someone forced me to create another account with different email id because they make me disable to post from that account by mass downvoting.)

(When I openly  comment about a downvote on a good question that I'm doing for a while with good reasoning  I think someone took it personally.)

This is not a question regarding math. But this is a question regarding moral code of members of this site.

When I'm about to join this site , I've a illusion that this site is about advanced mathematics or mathematics at research level at least basic research ( relative to Overflow) .

But I understood the game here  and going to mention in my viewpoint :

(1) Some people here increase the reputation by answering elementary question and then downvote the questions they don't understand

(2) People who downvote a relatively good question should tell what's wrong with the question, it can save a lot of time if it's a trivial question or mistake. Or if it's not it's a high possibility of getting ignored by person who really know something.

(3) Someone is mass downvoting my uploads
So I ask all moderators for help to resolve this issue.( [image: Proof]

(4) Some elementary (fun but non beneficiary (to research)) questions are upvoted to like few hundreds. I don't see this a fit for this site as it is for research purpose, you can see a lot of them on site. (I'm not saying don't ask such questions but saying at least categorize such type and reputation regarding it.)

(I don't have greed for reputation it's just that here people judge by reputation so it's highly unlikely to get an answer to the question which is downvoted.)

I think this is a serious issue. Please do the needful.

(I don't wanna criticize anybody. Everyone is right at their respective places but personalized behavior is not good on a professional site like this.)

(Edit : I'd like to add one more observation : 
When I post a serious question on stack exchange without much of details it gets downvoted . But when I post the same question with details on overflow It get lots of upvotes . This happened with me a lot.

This could be a proof of serious ignorance !!?? )

Comment: Although this is probably not the place for it, but I resonate with your points, especially point #2. If people are only allowed to downvote for specific reasons (and not merely for trivial errors or because they don't understand in a vague sense of the term), I think this is to the benefit of everyone -- except perhaps for quirky downvoters, which I agree exist. After all, it's humans that use this site.

Comment: @Allawonder : I definitely know this is not the place . But where else should I post all this is happening with me here .So I posted it here .

Comment: I support the first two points wholeheartedly. People not understanding some ingenious questions simply downvote them without any sort of comments on them. Plus, some people here are extremely rude. My friend stopped using StackExchange because of this. This, I believe should be stopped.

Comment: @E.Bombieri I don't really know too. Perhaps the Meta? But I'll let a mod come along and put things right. But I agree this is something that's got to be addressed.

Comment: @Sen47 I'm depressed because of this , literally crying . I'm working hard without any strong guidance and someone who has a reputation ( probably by answering elementary questions) couldn't understand the criticality and non-triviality  of the question simply downvotes it ?

Comment: @E.Bombieri I feel you, friend. This is a serious problem and I feel that the moderators of the site should make sure that the power of downvoting isn't misused. Same for closing off of questions.

Comment: I just want to say, pre-emptively, that downvotes on meta do not mean the same thing on meta as they do on the main site. If you get downvotes here, it usually means that people disagree with the point you're trying to get across. Note that it has no impact on your reputation on the site whatsoever. It also doesn't mean that the community aren't taking your concerns seriously. PS I'm sorry you've had such a horrible experience here. :-(

Comment: @Theo Bendit thank you ,sir . It's just that I joined this site with high hopes. Some of questions I posted I know they are trivial but they are just to clear my doubts as I don't have a strong guidance .

Comment: Check out [this discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13592/a-certain-kind-of-serial-downvoting).

Comment: @E.Bombieri I'm sorry about your experience. You should flag a post to have a moderator check for serial downvoting. Two things about your post here are, first, what do you mean by mass downvoting of your "uploads"? Are they questions, answers or both? Also, you wrote "When I'm about to join this site , I've a illusion that this site is about advanced mathematics or mathematics at research level at least basic research ( relative to Overflow) ." However, this site's basic description is "Q&A for people studying math at *any* level and professionals in related fields" (emphasis is mine).

Comment: There is no point posting here about "mass downvoting" of your posts, as there's not a thing ordinary users can do about it. The software does automatically spot instances of targeted downvoting, and fixes it. Flagging for moderator attention is your other recourse. Most of the points you raise have been discussed ad nauseam here already – have a look around.

Comment: @John Omielan : I know what the sites for, sir but like 70% of questions on this site can be found in any material if someone care to check neatly . So I may have thought that this is a site for when you run out all your options ?!! ( Out of option is case relative but you have internet basically so you could investigate properly)

Comment: "Mass downvoting" meant for questions

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you for reply . I'm frustrated so I first posted it on mathstack then someone transffered it to here

Comment: @Gerry Myerson You said "The software does automatically spot instances of targeted downvoting, and fixes it" . This is the second time this is happening to me . First ones also as it is . No repair .!

Comment: I'd like to add one more observation : When I post a serious question on stack exchange without much of details it gets downvoted . But when I post the same question with details on overflow It get lots of upvotes . This happened with me a lot.

This could be a proof of serious ignorance !!??

Comment: @Gerry Myerson "Flagging for moderator attention is your other recourse"  how to proceed for this .( I've never looked into such stuff so I'm relatively new for this)

Comment: I didn't downvote your questions, but I'm pretty sure that the reason that some people do it is that you are not really providing any [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) whatsoever. Your questions will be much better received if you explain where the problems come from, and provide some motivation for why you (or anybody else) would care about knowing the answer. Also, it's much easier to give relevant answers if you say something about your own thoughts on the problem, and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Hand Lundmark Sometimes I didn't provide details doesn't mean that I'm asking question without trying . Most of the time the analysis is long so it's painstaking to post it as I'm not used to electronic media  I'm a paper and pencil guy . I'm just seeking help when I ask . I just need directions not spoon-feeding answers most of the times . So sometimes I didn't provide with details . But from now on will do.

Comment: It occurs to me, Bombieri, that you may not have enough points to raise flags. Go to some question where you feel you have been downvoted unfairly, and you *might* see something at the bottom of the question like $$\text{share edit close flag}$$ If it's there, you click on flag, and there's a way to give the reason for flagging. If the software isn't reversing downvotes, that may mean that it's not one voter targeting you, but several voters each independently finding something wrong with a different question each. Anyway, as I wrote, we can't do anything here; moderators may be able to.

Comment: By the way, you have no way to know that users downvote questions they don't understand, and it does your case no good to make such unfounded and unsubstantiated accusations against other users.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I flagged the post for help ,thanks ! My accusations are not baseless I've strong reasons to believe the statement . For example see the following question :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346001/graph-of-1-zetan-where-n-runs-through-positive-real-numbers it has 2 downvotes 1upvote .    I know the question is relatively elementary but not as elementary as of 2 downvoted .

Comment: Also you can see the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3346123/integrate-int-0-infty-frac-e-ixlog2-eixlog2e2%cf%80x-1-dx. I know the answer to this question already I just need different methods of solutions . 2 downvoted! So, the accusations ( out of anger)!

Comment: Also, I'm tired of explaining .

Comment: I think you need to shake this impression that you have of downvotes being proportional to how elementary a question is. Elementary questions are fine, so long as they meet the [site guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for asking questions. It'd be sad if you decided to quit, but given, as you say, you're more of a pen-and-paper kind of person, you might find that asking questions here is more trouble than it's worth. I recommend giving it another chance, trying to include some context in your questions, but look after yourself first. :-)

Comment: "When I post a serious question on stack exchange without much of details it gets downvoted . But when I post the same question with details on overflow It get lots of upvotes .  This happened with me a lot.

This could be a proof of serious ignorance !!?? " Are you sure you wrote what you meant to write? From what you wrote it ought to be an obvious conclusion that adding the details is what helps and should be done.

Comment: You do not know who downvoted your questions, Bombieri. You have no idea whether they are ignorant or brilliant. You know nothing about them, except that they have a lower opinion of your questions than you have. So please stop going on about things you know nothing about. Stick to the facts, and take on board what people here are trying to tell you.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  sorry , if it seems rude  but I'm controlling myself for long time here . So , the opinion . This is going out of hand for me. ( I could likely guess from the comments who downvoted and see their profile what they have answered the most and surprise : primary calculus !)

Comment: Step away from the keyboard. Do something else, until you can come back with a clear head, unaffected by anger, able to view things objectively, able to take on board what quid and others are telling you. Maybe take a day or two off from this place. It can work for you, if you work with it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you , sir!!!

Answer (score 14):

First, let me stress that indeed the down-votes seem not good. It is basically never alright to down-vote in a string. (It is not even advisable to do this when each post does merit a downvote; I do not say this is the case here, neither do I say it is not the case here, it is a general point I want to make.) We will look into it. There is also a script that might undo it automatically.

Now, what you should do in such a situation is to raise a flag for moderator attention with the original account so that we can look into it. You could also have posted to this meta-site with your original account. You could have posted in the Math Mods office chat. Or, finally you could also have used "contact us" to get in touch with somebody at the site. (Maybe not all of this is obvious but at least one of these ways ought to have been discoverable.)

Further, you presumably got a page that offered some explanation why you cannot post questions anymore, [something pointing you to the relevant help page on question bans](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). Did you study it?

Instead of doing something of the above, you created another account and posted an off-topic rant on the main site, while you were not even allowed to post any question at all to the main site. Right, you think this is all unfair and unjust, but if you think it's that handful of votes that is the problem that's a massive misconception. Maybe, not even this is clear, it was what pushed you over the edge, but it is not at all the main reason. A main reason should be your numerous (self-)deleted posts.

Thus, I recommend that you get familiar with what is and is not expected on this site and adapt your conduct accordingly. The main problem is how you used the site, the handful of possibly targeted down-votes is not alright but overall a detail, granted an annoying one but still.

Comment: I delete them after the downvote guessing something is wrong with me.

Comment: There aren't any downvotes on some of them. Stick to the facts, please.

Comment: "A main reason should be your numerous (self-)deleted posts". You asked about self deleted post so I gave you reason why

Comment: Well, but the reason you gave cannot apply to all of them because some of them do not have a downvote. Now, in a way that's a tangent. It's maybe relevant in being further evidence for what I consider a bit of a problem with your attitude. Always some adversary outside thing is presented as the reason, while the reality is not quite like that.

Comment: No ,I know, but 7 downvoted in 2 minutes , is he even reading?

Comment: Now my reputation drops down to 53 from 130 how you'll explain this . This is a clear case of personal revange !!?? See my answer below for proof.

Comment: I've no intention to run a rant but I've nowhere to go . Also not much used to the site . So I asked someone and they recommend to post me .

Comment: The reason for the drop was explained already. To repeat,  it's due to the removal of some other account from the site.

Answer (score -7):

You all wanna see what I'm talking about : 
[image]

Comment: Please someone suggest how to delete a stack exchange account from respective mail id . I mean permanently delete

Comment: You know, this is a complicated site, and we all have a lot to learn about how it works, but, honestly, you are making yourself look like an idiot by utterly misunderstanding events. You were not removed! Someone who had upvoted a lot of your work was removed! (I'm assuming that you didn't upvote your own posts, using your second account – if you did that, you really are an idiot, as that's one of the best ways to get thrown out of the site entirely). Calm down, please, read quid's post, and take it to heart.

Comment: I understood my mistake . Please close the discussion.

Comment: Apologies everyone for my rude behavior I'm not thinking straight .

Comment: I'm not going to return here with this account so messaging me is in vain . If there's way or someone can delete this account please do the needful.